# Parallel For Each Over Data Tables in a Data Set

Tags: vb.net, datatable, parallel-processing

In VB.NET, can a parallel loop be performed on the tables inside a data set?
This has been answered.

My project is this:

1. Read a CSV file into a data table in memory.
2. Group the rows by sorting the data.
3. Process the data in synchronous loop detecting each group by a change in key values.

There are many separate processes that read these CSV files which each have their own layout and processing specifics.

My goal is to process these "groups" of data in parallel without using Entity Framework.

Is the Data Set/Data Table approach the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. A `DataSet` and a `DataTable` are in memory collections. So if you can process them independently it's a good candidate for a parallel `For Each`.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    dataSet.Tables.Cast(Of DataTable),
    Sub(table)
        ProcessTable(table)
    End Sub
)
```

Comment: Thank you; that answers my base question.  Let me expand on my original question to include the scope of what I'm trying to do and see if there is a better method.

Comment: I have edited the original question.  If a new question is preferred, I could do that.

Comment: @Acavier: well, normally yes, because the questions is now different to the original. Now you ask a subjective question(best in what way, why you have chosen DataSet at all, what are the alternatives?). It's also better to show your code and to focus on actual issues you've faced

Comment: Thank you.  My issues come from trying to maintain the Entity Framework EDMX file across so many of our client databases that I want to start from scratch and come up with the best way to process the data from CSV files in a parallel loop.

Comment: @Acavier: You can use whatever collection you prefer, maybe a `List(Of DataBaseSchema)` would be better. Why you need the `DataSet` at all?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the DataBaseSchema object.

Comment: @Acavier that was just the class name that first came to my mind, it doesnt exist yet and you can create it.